# Is it possible to link Xamarin on Visual Studio 2013 to SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to connect to SQL Server 2012 Management Studio?

As my whole project database is in management studio and I need to extract data to display in the Xamarin android app is it possible?

And is there any good tutorials I can follow as I am touching Xamarin for the first time in my life.

Comment: You should build a web service in front of your database and then the Xamarin mobile app can consume its services. Never expose a database over the internet.

Comment: @LexLi is it possible to not use a web service? and is there any good tutorial on xamarin consuming a service really need it as reference

Comment: No, impossible. If your mobile apps directly connect to the database, then anyone else can see the connection string and break into your database.

Comment: Not sure "Impossible" is the correct word. Currently there are no canned drivers or any easy out of the box way to do it. Anything is possible. Given enough time Money and suicidal tendencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest is going to be to put your SQL Server up on Azure and then Use Azure Mobile Services to Publish it as a rest API and Consume it locally within your app. Theres a good amount of documentation about how to get your database into Azure. As for how to use Azure Mobile Services take a look at

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Azure-backend-for-Android-and-iOS-apps/01--Azure-overview-for-Android--iOS-developers

5 Hours of step by step how to do it

And yes once its up in Azure you can then access it both from MS SQL Manager and Xamarain (via the api)